# Stack Overflow account security is vulnerable

Tags: feature-request, security

As Stack Overflow is a worldwide recognized community. I think the account safety of the users should not be compromised.
It looks like our Stack Overflow accounts are vulnerable to password hack attacks.
For example: Brute-force attack.

For this, I suggest Stack Overflow to add a new layer of security while changing the password of our account.

This can be done by sending an one-time confirmation password on either one of the below platforms while a user changes his/her Stack Overflow account password.

- Email
- Mobile phone

Also, I've found one bad feature that Stack Overflow allows to enter a new password which is same as the old password.
It think this functionality should be disabled by adding some validation rules.

Any other changes related to security of Stack Overflow accounts will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I think some accounts (users with high reputation) may be compromised in order to take revenge or to lead in reputation competition by disabling a hacked account.

Comment: The lack of these features does not necessarily implicate vulnerability. Also, allowing the user to change into an old password isn't something SE should be concerned of. It is your own duty to spice up passwords and occasionally change them into new ones.

Comment: Mostly a cross-site duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232256/security-hole-password-change-dialog-doesnt-ask-for-a-users-current-password

Comment: _"It looks like our Stack Overflow accounts are vulnerable to password hack attacks"_: That's a bold claim. Can you back it up with an example?

Comment: Two-factor authentication is complex to implement, probably not something on the team's to-do list and it arguably isn't necessary either. If you really want any of that for an account where the potential for damage is *very* limited, using a Google account to log in should have exactly the same effect as far as I can see.

Comment: also related: [Logins can be added/removed without reauthenticating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276933/134300)

Comment: @Pekka웃 technically Two-factor authentication already exists on StackExchange if you use Google or Facebook. you can use Two-factor authentication on those to log in and use those to log into Stack Exchange

Comment: @Memor-X yup, that's what I meant

Answer (score 18):

Stack Exchange is already covered as far as "Brute-force" attacks go:

> [image]

I got this verification request after only 3 phoney (manual) login attempts using Stack Overflow's own login option.
I'm sure there are more (invisible) measures in place for "attacks" on a larger scale.

The Google/Facebook login options are basically as secure as they can be. There's no way anyone's going to brute-force those aside from driving an actual tank into their datacenters.

Comment: The image of a tank driving into a datacenter as a "brute force" attack is *awesome*.